# C# Json property not displaying the value properly

Tags: c#, json

In C#, I am currently using the following method to prettify my json:

```
public static string JsonPrettify(this string json)
{
    using var jDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jDoc, new JsonSerializerOptions 
    { 
        WriteIndented = true,
        //Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
    });
}
```

However, some property values that has an escaped double quotes are being displayed weirdly. For example, the following actual json (please note that this json is just an example and not the full json):

```
{
"CompanyCode": "\":<"
}
```

After using the C# method, it is being displayed as:

```
{
"CompanyCode": "\u0022:\u003C",
}
```

I have tried setting the encoder but that is still not fixing my issue. How do I fix this issue to display the json properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting the encoder _will_ fix the issue as far as the question (and the code therein) is concerned. Just uncomment and use `JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`, and the string returned by your JsonPrettify method _will_ feature `"\":<"` instead of `"\u0022:\u003C"`. Proof: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9H1D0J

Comment: "to prettify my json" - Just because of the curiosity what are you doing with it after this?

Comment: I am sending out an email with the json. That's why i need my json formatted correctly (ie. indented etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can uncomment and use JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping, but if you want more safety, the easiest way would be the fix a json string using RegEx or you can use this code as example

```
json = json.Replace(@"\u0022",@"\""").Replace(@"\u003C","<");
```

Comment: Thanks. So i am sending emails to my teams channel and teams has a weird way of displaying json. After uncommenting the JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping, the characters are now displayed properly.